# How to design a has_many through: in rails 6 with Characters and Movies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

i was wondering if you could help me with this. I've been struggling for two days now.
I'm trying to build the models for movies, actors, and the studio on rails.
So what i've got so far is that a STUDIO has_many movies and many characters (as in MCU has iron man, thor, hulk, etc as characters, or DCU has Batman, Joker, etc...). Also, a MOVIE has_many characters through a STUDIO. And a single character has_many MOVIES thorugh STUDIO.

so my design is something like this(Trying to design with postgresql database)

```
rails g model studio name:string movies_ids:Array characters_ids:Array #movies_ids will hold an array of all the ids of the movies that 
                                                                       belong to the studio, same goes for characters_ids

rails g model movie title:string studio_id:integer characters_ids:Array #a movie belongs to only one studio, 
                                                                        but has many characters, so an array of all the characters_ids.

rails g model character name:string studio_id:integer movies_ids:Array #a character belongs to a single studio but can appear in many movies, 
                                                                        so an array of movies_ids
```

Is this model designing correct? am i missing something? by now you have probably realised i'm a newbie.

So, after that, in my models i would have something like:

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :studio
    has_many :movies, through: :studio
end

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :studio
    has_many :characters, through: :studio
end

class Studio < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :movies
    has_many :characters
end
```

What i want to achieve is to be able to say Studio.Movie.all() and retrieve all the movies from a studio.
Also Movie.characters.all() and retrieve all the characters from a movie
And also Character.movies.all() retrieves all the movies a characters has been in.
In the future i will have many Studios, so DCU, MCU, Warner, Pixar, etc...

If you could guide me through just a bit or at least point me in the right direction i'd really appreciate it. I'm having a hard time grasping on how to achieve this. I've been using different youtube videos to guide me through but none of them are desingning something like what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want, the codes to run on terminal would be:

```
rails g model studio name:string      
rails g model movie title:string studio:belongs_to
rails g model character name:string studio:belongs_to
```

No need to create the `characters_ids:Array`, because when you add `has_many :characters` Rails take care of the rest.

**UPDATED:**

- `Movie and Characters has a join table`
- `Studio has many Movies`
- `Studio has many Characters`.

The commands:

```
rails g model Studio name:string      
rails g model Movie title:string studio:belongs_to
rails g model Character name:string studio:belongs_to
rails g model MovieCharacter character:belongs_to movie:belongs_to
```

The models:

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :movie
   has_many :character_movies
   has_many :movies, through: :character_movies
end

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :studio
    has_many :character_movies
    has_many :characters, through: :character_movies
end

class Studio < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :movies
    has_many :characters
end

class MovieCharacter < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :movies
    belongs_to :characters
end
```

Comment: Thank you for using your time to help me out. I will try your way of making the associations as they seem to make the most sense.
About the " rails g model character name:string movie:belong_to " doesn't this map a one-to one relationship between a character model and a movie? as in a single character can belong to only one movie?
For example: Iron man belongs to the movie Iron man 1, but i also have iron man 2 and iron man 3, so when i try to map iron man to the three movies, and then use Character.where(name:"iron man").movie.all() will i still get the three movies? or only one?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the way I wrote It will be one-to-one. Now I understood that you need to have the same Iron man character record linked to a lot of different movies. It will be necessary to a join table. You can create a CharacterMovie join model, with rails g model CharacterMovie character:belongs_to movie:belongs_to. And add a 'has_many: movies, through: :character_movies' on Character and 'has_many: characters, through: :character_movies' on Movie. Because if you use Studio as a join table, when querying something like Movie.characters.all you will receive all chars from that studio.

Comment: Well i followed your advice and created a separate join table for basically everything lol. It worked. I have a join table for Studio and Movies (studio_movies) and a join table for Movies and Characters (movie_characters) and some more models and join tables and now my relationships are working as desired. I can now call Studio.movies and get a list of movies and also i can call Character.movies or Movie.characters. Thank you for your help. Now i have another issue with rendering my data as JSON and i made another thread for that.

Comment: Happy to know @GuidoMedina! If possible, mark this answer as accepted!